# MessageBox.Show() with owner argument

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

I would like to use MessageBox.Show() in VB.NET with the owner argument as follows:

```
MessageBox.Show(owner As IWin32Window,...)
```

It is my understanding that if this code was in a Windows form, you would simply pass "Me" (VB.NET) or "this" (C#) as the owner argument.  However, my code is part of an Excel COM add-in and the owner argument must somehow be tied to a particular Excel window.

So, how can I take an Excel window object and convert that to a IWin32Window that I can pass to MessageBox.Show() in VB.NET? I'll settle for C# code if I can easily convert it to VB.NET.

Comment: Well, you could try `MessageBox.Show(Control.FromHandle(excelWindow.Hwnd), "Text")`  but honestly, [I doubt it'll work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/581841/996081).

Comment: You could try to create a class (wrapper) which accepts an excel window in the ctor. Implement IWin32Window and return the handle. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn292510.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass the owner window to Show() method overload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631491/how-do-you-pass-the-owner-window-to-show-method-overload)

Comment: That possible duplicate was C#.  I needed VB.NET.  Sure, the conversion is trivial for some, but not others.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what's the purpose of the `owner` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already pointed you to the [C# version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631491/how-do-you-pass-the-owner-window-to-show-method-overload). Just write the VB.NET version of it:

```
Public Class WindowWrapper
    Implements IWin32Window
    Private hwnd As IntPtr

    Public Sub New(handle As IntPtr)
        hwnd = handle
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(handle As Integer)
        hwnd = New IntPtr(handle)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Handle As IntPtr Implements IWin32Window.Handle
        Get
            Return hwnd
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And use like:

```
MessageBox.Show(New WindowWrapper(app.Hwnd), _
    '' other arguments... _
)
```

Where `app` is your variable that stores the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application interface.